# Unable to find how to install pandas library in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio

After successfully installing Python 3.7 as a project option language in Visual Studio 2019, I am unable (lack the skills) to find a means to install the pandas library.

Currently working on learning how to read an Excel file in Python. When using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

the error returned is: **unresolved import 'pandas'**

Huge thank yous for any help or guidance.

Comment: Try `pip install pandas` or read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html) or [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html).

Comment: I know it's unsolicited advice but can I recommend you try Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @mosc9575
Thank you! Followed the install for Anaconda and then used its method for importing pandas. Sometimes, the first steps are the most difficult. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Riley
Thank you. Next on my list of what to explore.